# How To Get Array From Session Object In Kohana?

Tags: php, arrays, session, kohana, kohana-3

I'm using Kohana 3.0 and I need to get array from `Session` object.

For example:

```
$session = Session::instance();

$session->set(
    'myArray'
    array(
        'key1' => 'foo',
        'key2' => 'bar'
    )
);

// How to get specific array element?
```

I thought that this will work, but it returned `null`.

```
$session->get('myArray.key2');
```

After thinking and thinking (ha, ha!) I think-out this...

```
$myArray = $session->get('myArray');
$key1 = $myArray['key1'];
```

Is it okay? Is there better way?

P.S. When [array dereferencing](https://www.php.net/migration55.new-features#migration55.new-features.const-dereferencing) will be available... gonna use it! =]

```
$key1 = $session->get('myArray')['key1']; // Lets hope that this work!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Retrieve basic var and use standard
   Arr helper

   ```
    Arr::get($session->get('myArray', array()), 'key1');
   ```
2. Work with session data as array:

   ```
    $data = & $session->as_array();
    $key1 = Arr::path($data, 'myArray.key1');
    $data['myArray']['key2'] = 'foo'; // also you can set data
   ```